# Google spreadsheet - move/copy row with image in it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

The code which I am using -

```
    var row = range.getRow();
    var numColumns = activeSheet.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Open");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    activeSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);    
    activeSheet.deleteRow(row);
```

Which works fine for rows which have only text. There are some rows like -

[image]

Is there some way the images can also be copied/moved together with row data? Seems `Range.moveTo` only moves data.

Answer (score 1):

Use copyTo(destination, options) not moveTo(target)

The moveTo() docs do state:

> Cut and paste (both format and values) from this range to the target range.

i.e. values, not formulas.

copyTo docs:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object)

```
source.copyTo(ss.getRange('Sheet2!A1'), {contentsOnly: true});
```

You could add a feature request to the issue tracker.